# Excel counting dates, a row of dates, some duplicates, for use in a graph

Tags: excel

I have a call log exported from my phone, and I want to graph number of calls per day and do some other analytics, because of how its exported, I have a list of calls with a Datetime (see below), my first thought was a =COUNTIF(C:C, "01/09/2018") for each date I need, but something to do with how excel formats dates doesn't like it, even if I convert the Datetime to plain text, any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You get a `#NAME?` error, meaning that your formula is not recognised by Excel. Try using `COUNTIF` instead of `COUNITIF`.

Comment: OK, yes, that didn't help, my bad, I fixed that and now all I get is 0, despite there being dates to count

Comment: You have datetime in one column and days in another. First change the day format to a real date, not text. Then use COUNTIFS with 2 criteria: `>=` and the date, and `<` and the date + 1.

Comment: @BigBen Huzzah, thanks for that, I ended up using an additional day + 1 column rather than mess about with the syntax of it but I its working now with
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&G2,B:B,"<="&H2)
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&Day,B:B,"<="&Day plus one)

Comment: `"<"&H2` - you don't want to include the next day, remove the equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` and make sure your day column contains actual dates.

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,">="&G2,D:D,"<"&G2+1)
```

[image]